# std::vector becomes invalid after calling size() on it inside filterAcceptsRow

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, stl, qt-creator

I am using a selfmade QSortFilterProxyModel to do the filtering and sorting of a model in my application.

Here is the filterAcceptsRow function:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool
SkillSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int p_row, const QModelIndex& p_parent) const
{
    QModelIndex currentIndex = sourceModel()->index(p_row, 0, p_parent);
    SkillModelItem* currentItem = (SkillModelItem*)currentIndex.internalPointer();

    // Check the item
    bool accept = filterAcceptsItem(currentItem);

    // We may hide a category if it is empty
    if (accept && currentItem->isCategory && !_showEmptyCategories)
    {
        // Iterate over the children to find out if any will be accepted
        // And if so, accept the category
        int numChildren = currentItem->children.size();
        accept = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
        {
            SkillModelItem* item = currentItem->children[i];
            if (filterAcceptsItem(item))
            {
                accept = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return result
    return accept; 
}
```

Here is what it is supposed to do: I think the exact nature of the SkillModelItem is not important here, but you should understand that the same model item class is used for skill categories and skills themselves. The filterAcceptsRow function calls filterAcceptsItem to see if the particular item should be shown or not. That works well.

However, if the item is a category, its children should also be checked to see if it has any accepted children, and if so, the category should be shown.

Should work in theory, but what happens in practice is that after **currentItem->children.size()** is called, the currentItem->children (which is a std::vector) becomes invalid! It returns the correct size, but if I call it again, the size is now some random number. And accessing the child items in the for loop after crashes the application.

I have no idea what is going on here. The application is not threaded (at least I do not use any threads). I am using Qt Creator on Windows, using MinGW as the compiler. I also tried using MSVC but that will not even compile as it claims it cannot find any header files (which MinGW can find without problems). Also tried recompiling, re-running qmake, etc. All to no avail.

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

If it helps, you can look at the sources here: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/TheSHEEEP/SR5-Shaman/tree/master/SR5-Shaman)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a debugger problem.

If I do not step through at runtime, the function works just fine.

Seems like there is a bug in either Qt Creator or the MinGW version coming with it.